# How can I get the Hex representation of a Unicode character in C#?

Tags: c#, string, unicode

Here is my code:

```
var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("ABCD"));

hexString = Regex.Replace(hexString, "[-]", string.Empty);
```

I get the result:

```
4100420043004400
```

I should get:

```
0041004200430044
```

That looks like a trailing, ending with "00" problem but I actually get other errors when trying it with special characters.

For instance the greek letter **Ο**

Should be `039f` but my code gives me `9F03`

I even tried the below code that I found in another question:

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in ba)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    return hex.ToString();
}
```

The result is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get Unicode encoded in [Little Endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Try [Encoding.BigEndianUnicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.text.encoding.bigendianunicode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it will give you what you want (i.e. `0041004200430044` for 'ABCD') - just change Unicode to BigEndianUnicode.